# Retrieving Posts from Kuaishou Using Their API

Tags: json, postman, httprequest

I'm integrating Kuaishou functionalities into my application and need to specifically fetch individual posts using their API, aiming to retrieve detailed data such as video URLs, titles, and descriptions for a given post's URL. Navigating through Kuaishou's predominantly Chinese documentation has proven challenging, and I haven't located the precise endpoints or parameters required for this task. Could anyone with experience in Kuaishou's API share insights or examples on how to achieve this? Tips on handling authentication and identifying the necessary request parameters would also be highly appreciated.

I tried to fetch a specific post's data by loading its page URL directly in Postman. I was expecting to retrieve the post's content, including the video URL, title, and description. Instead, I received a JSON response with no error message but an uninformative result code, as shown below:

```
{
    "result": 2,
    "error_msg": null,
    "request_id": "708505808042597636"
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.